# How do i call a function first and then the second in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I want to call `checkifPresentInActiveProjLib` function first and after that `checkifPresentInClosedProjLib` function.How do I attain this?

```
checkifPresentInActiveProjLib(function(flgAc) {
    if (flgAc === "active_found")
        // do something

    $.ajax(...); // ajax call
});

checkifPresentInClosedProjLib(function(flgCl) {
    if (flgCl === "closed_found")
        // do something

    $.ajax(...); // ajax call
});
```

Comment: await checkifPresentInActiveProjLib() will do?

Comment: In your examples they are called one after the other. Do you mean after the ajax call of the first one ?

Comment: yes.. These two functions(checkifPresentInActiveProjLib and checkifPresentInClosedProjLib) are present inside a function called after button click.I want that after the ajax call of the checkifPresentInActiveProjLib() gets completed then it should call checkifPresentInClosedProjLib()

Comment: You can use async await to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript `Promise` object

```
  function  checkifPresentInActiveProjLib(flgAc) {
    if (flgAc === "active_found")
        alert('active_found');
};

function checkifPresentInClosedProjLib(flgCl) {
    if (flgCl === "closed_found")
        alert('closed_found');
};

function makeAjaxCall(){
   var promiseObj = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
         resolve(checkifPresentInActiveProjLib());
   });
 return promiseObj;
}

 makeAjaxCall().then(checkifPresentInClosedProjLib());
```

Comment: @programtreasures- Is this solution complete.Dont we resolve and reject the promoise?

Comment: I am getting error : checkifPresentInActiveProjLib is not defined and checkifPresentInClosedProjLib is not defined

Comment: please check now, and call your ajax inside the appropriate function

Comment: Can you explain in detail?

Comment: There was some issue with syntax.This code worked like a charm.Thank you so much for the help.Much appreciated..:-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use promises to hande async things. You need to modify your `checkifPresentInActiveProjLib` to return promise, in this case your promise is `$.ajax(...);` so you do `return $.ajax(...);` then simply call the next func in the following manner:

```
 checkifPresentInActiveProjLib(...)
.then(function() { 
      checkifPresentInClosedProjLib(args)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have async ajax calls in both functions. If you want to call the second one after the first one completed, you need to wait for the first function to be completed.

You can simply do that by calling the second function inside the ajax function part's response section in the first function.

```
checkifPresentInActiveProjLib(function(flgAc) {
    if (flgAc === "active_found")
        // do something

    $.ajax(...).done(function( data ) {
    // call second function here
  }););
});
```

Or you can use promises:

```
checkifPresentInActiveProjLib(function (flgAc) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (flgAc === 'active_found')
        // do something
        $.ajax(...)
                .done(function (data) {
                  if (data) resolve(data);
                })
                .fail(function (err) {
                  reject(err);
                });
    });
});
```

Then call functions as:

```
checkifPresentInActiveProjLib(...).then(data => checkifPresentInClosedProjLib(...)
```